# IE9 Invalid viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, internet-explorer, iis-7.5

I have 2 web servers that are identical and have round robin load balancing but on one of the servers I get the following error but only in IE9

```
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. [System.Web.HttpException]
Date occurred: 23/03/2015 11:50:16
   at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)
   at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.autogen_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Invalid viewstate. 
Client IP: X.X.X.X
Port: 63267
Referer: http://hgcmvl01v/MSMSelfService/AutoGen.aspx?page=666
Path: /MSMSelfService/AutoGen.aspx
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
ViewState: 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,/wEPDwULLTE2MzMxNDc3MjYPZBYCZg9kFgRmD2QWAgICDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlZ2QCBQ9kFgICAQ9kFgJmDxYCHglpbm5lcmh0bWwFihsNCkV4Y2VwdGlvbiBvZiB0eXBlICYjMzk7U3lzdGVtLldlYi5IdHRwVW5oYW5kbGVkRXhjZXB0aW9uJiMzOTsgd2FzIHRocm93bi4gW1N5c3RlbS5XZWIuSH... [System.Web.UI.ViewStateException]
Date occurred: 23/03/2015 11:50:16

    The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.  [System.FormatException]
    Date occurred: 23/03/2015 11:50:16
       at System.Convert.FromBase64_ComputeResultLength(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
       at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
       at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose)
       at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Deserialize(String serializedState, Purpose purpose)
       at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose)
       at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
```

Comment: could you check in IE10

Comment: are you explicitly storing some data in the ViewState? the exception appears to indicate that the information stored in the Viewstate is not properly encoded

Comment: I have managed to get to the bottom of the issue; the view state was storing information, to be used on a search. I removed the line of code and its now working 

Thanks guys for getting back to me

Answer (score 0):

The issue was down to the viewstate saving info and trying to reach a KB server witch wasnt setup, removed the code and now working